# Linux Mint reset NVIDIA GPU without a restart

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card

I would like to know if it is possible through the terminal to reset a GPU? To clarify, an example scenario where the card is overclocked too far and resets to Performance Level 0, or around 30% of standard speed.

Rebooting fixes this but the problem is I usually access this machine remotely over TeamViewer and need to remain connected while the card is reset.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can you use `nvidia-smi`, you can reset with:

```bash
sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset
```

or

```bash
sudo nvidia-smi -r
```

This comes from the `nvidia-smi` help: `nvidia-smi -h | grep reset`. It should work for your machine.

Other people may be using a server such as [DGX-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DGX-1). In that case, [you cannot reset individual GPUs](https://nvidia-esp.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4642/~/how-to-reset-gpus-on-dgx-1-systems):

> In the case of the DGX-1 and DGX-1V platforms, individual GPU's can not be reset because they are linked via nvlink, so all the GPU's have to be reset simultaneously.

This is the case in some computing clusters and on the Standard NV6 virtual machine on Azure:

```
$ sudo nvidia-smi -r
Resetting GPU 00003343:00:00.0 is not supported.
```